# Robo 3T able to bypass MongoDB auth=true

Tags: mongodb

I used robo 3t to login to a database and was surprised that I was able to write on the collection despite having a read only role, by adding a document via the GUI or sending commands through Robo 3T.

What could be the problem? On mongosh (mongo shell) I wasnt able to.

```
tonidoclouddb> db.getRole("test", {showPrivileges:true}) 
{
  role: 'test',
  db: 'tonidoclouddb',
  isBuiltin: false,
  roles: [],
  inheritedRoles: [],
  privileges: [
    {
      resource: {
        db: 'tonidoclouddb',
        collection: 'users'
      },
      actions: [ 'find' ]
    }
  ],
  inheritedPrivileges: [
    {
      resource: {
        db: 'tonidoclouddb',
        collection: 'users'
      },
      actions: [ 'find' ]
    }
  ]
}
```

````
{
  _id: 'tonidoclouddb.mynewuser',
  userId: UUID("46bdf5e7-fb0a-4616-a1ee-5fc46fd0f97f"),
  user: 'mynewuser',
  db: 'tonidoclouddb',
  roles: [ { role: 'test', db: 'tonidoclouddb' } ],
  mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
} ```
````

[image: Robo 3T user login]

[image: Robo 3T response]

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Either you have different credentials when you log in using this tool **or** there's a serious bug in MongoDB (I'm **shocked**!).

Comment: Did you enable authentication and did you restart the mongod database? Verify which privileges you actually got by your role with `db.getRole()`

Comment: tonidoclouddb> db.getRole("test")
{
  role: 'test',
  db: 'tonidoclouddb',
  isBuiltin: false,
  roles: [],
  inheritedRoles: []
}

Comment: ```tonidoclouddb> db.getRole("test", {showPrivileges:true})
{
  role: 'test',
  db: 'tonidoclouddb',
  isBuiltin: false,
  roles: [],
  inheritedRoles: [],
  privileges: [
    {
      resource: { db: 'tonidoclouddb', collection: 'users' },
      actions: [ 'find' ]
    }
  ],
  inheritedPrivileges: [
    {
      resource: { db: 'tonidoclouddb', collection: 'users' },
      actions: [ 'find' ]
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: Please put additional information to your question (by "Edit") instead as a comment.

Comment: You also need to run [db.getUser()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getUser/) to see what is granted to your account

Comment: Done @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: And then finally the response of your insert command. Verify carefully which user was used in Robo 3T.

Comment: Done added 2 pictures

Comment: Check with `db.runCommand("connectionStatus")`, you may have more than one user authenticated on that connection.